# How can i get products from a remote database in real time by filters in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, collection, rest-api

This request is for an auto parts store. The products are filtered by car make, model, year, etc. When a client apply a filter I need to make an API call to manufacturer server, get products and display those products and the client must be able to purchase those products.

Is there any module for this?
I do not know where to begin with this.

Comment: you can use catalogProductRepositoryV1 with search criteria

Comment: Thanks Aditya. I am new to magento. Can you give me little more details?

Comment: Okay, do know how to call APIs ?

Comment: I do nkow how to call APIs but i am not familiar with magento's API. Also the remote database it is not the same structure.

Comment: ohk then i am adding an answer, let me know if any query

Comment: Hello @Leonida i have added an answer, if it solves your concern then mark as right, it will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

**Search criteria will be helpful**

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][<index>][filters][<index>][field]=<field_name>
searchCriteria[filter_groups][<index>][filters][<index>][value]=<search_value>
searchCriteria[filter_groups][<index>][filters][<index>][condition_type]=<operator>
```

> where

- `field` is an attribute name.
- `value` specifies the value to search for.
- `condition_type` specifies condition[ex: eq , finset, like, from, to]

**for your case**

```
http://magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=78&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```